# How to visualize metrics application insights?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I am adding metrics to my application insights, but I don't know how to visualize values I track. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.

My code looks like:

```
    public void AddCustomMetric(String metricName,double Amount,  List<Property> additionalProperties)
    {
        CreateMetric(metricName, Amount, additionalProperties);
    }

    private void CreateMetric(String metricName, double amount, List<Property> additionalProperties)
    {
        List<String> metrycsNameList = new List<String>();
        List<String> metrycsValueList = new List<String>();
        try
        {
           additionalProperties.ForEach(property => metrycsValueList.Add(property.Value));
           additionalProperties.ForEach(property => metrycsNameList.Add(property.Name));
           Metric metric = _client.GetMetric(new MetricIdentifier("MetricNamespace", metricName, metrycsNameList));
            //metrycsValueList.ForEach(metricValue => metric.TrackValue(Amount, metricValue, "hola", "adios"));
            AddMetricValues(metric, amount, metrycsValueList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CustomMetricException("CustomMetricException", "Error adding a Custom Metric", ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }

    private void AddMetricValues(Metric metric, double amount, List<String> metrycsValueList)
    {
        int numberOfElements = metrycsValueList.Count;

        switch (numberOfElements)
        {
            case 1:
                metric.TrackValue(amount, metrycsValueList[0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                metric.TrackValue(amount, metrycsValueList[0], metrycsValueList[1]);
                break;
            case 3:
                metric.TrackValue(amount, metrycsValueList[0], metrycsValueList[1], metrycsValueList[2]); 
                break;
            .........
```

I call the method like:

```
public void AddCustomMetricTestTupla()
    {
        List<Property> propertiesList = new List<Property>();
        propertiesList.Add(new Property("propertyExample", "value"));
        propertiesList.Add(new Property("propertyExample1", "value2"));
        propertiesList.Add(new Property("propertyExample2", "value3"));

        //Tests method AddCustomMetric giving a tuple as a param.
        using (AzureInsightsClient azureInsightsClient = new AzureInsightsClient(myClientKey))
        {
            azureInsightsClient.FlushMetrics();
            azureInsightsClient.AddCustomMetric("Example", 2, propertiesList);
        }

    }
```

I don't know if I'm getting the track correctly or not, because I can't see anything on Azure Application Insights.

[Azure Portal Application Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HICqb.png)

Maybe I have an error on my code? Anyone help?

Comment: What is `AzureInsightsClient`? (And what does the `Dispose` inside of it do?)  and what does `FlushMetrics` do?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You have to click on Metrics and look for your metric you have made.

[image]

And you can get the graphs by selecting it.

[image]

You can also check them by query at Analysis.